# Delete HTML element in Chrome DevTools without deleting its children?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm tinkering around using Chrome DevTools on someone's site to clean up their code and make things look the way they've requested.

So far I've been unable to delete an HTML element without also deleting its child elements (I right click on the `<div>` I want to delete and click **'delete element'** - but this also removes all child element inside it).

However, I only want to remove the outer `<div>` wrapping because it's redundant and unnecessary (the code is a mess with divs inside of divs inside of divs for no reason). When I double click on the `<div>` and use the delete key to erase it, I'm unable to remove the outer carrots and when I click back out, the `<div>` reappears.

I'm almost sure I'm missing a simple step - can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why don't you right click and edit HTML?
This way you can delete only the portion of code you don't want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on the div you want to remove and choose 'edit as html'. Remove the lines you don't want and then click outside the editable area to close it.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click the element, choose **Edit as HTML**, delete the start and end tags, and save. That should move the child elements out of it and into its parent automatically. Deleting the element will *always* also delete its children; double-clicking it only lets you edit its tag name and not its entire markup.

Comment: You can also simply drag the child nodes out of the parent then delete the empty parent if that's practical (may not be in cases with many children). Either way edit as HTML for most cases is the best option which is why I've added this as a comment not an answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Gave @trevor accepted answer bc he was minutes before you (he then deleted and re posted which is why he's now 1 min after). If I could give to both I would but your rep doesn't look too in need haha. THANK YOU

Comment: @Kyle Vassella: No biggie, he didn't repost his answer, so he's still first :)

Comment: @Kyle Vassella I'm totally cool with you giving BoltClock the accepted answer if you like, as his explanation is more in depth.

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for being cool and making stackoverflow a friendly place to hang out.